# There is something about Javascript inheritance that I can't understand

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming, prototypal-inheritance

I was reading [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) from Mozilla Developer Network, time to learn so serious Javascript before start using node.js.

Anyway, inheritance thing seems so obscure to me. Copy and paste from the documentation:

```javascript
// define the Person Class
function Person() {}

Person.prototype.walk = function(){
  alert ('I am walking!');
};
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert ('hello');
};
```

This is easy, but things get complicated with `Student` inheritance. Does anyone else think that the following three statements do essentially the same thing?

```javascript
// define the Student class
function Student() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  Person.call(this);
}

// inherit Person
Student.prototype = new Person();

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

I understand the first one (calling the parent constructor) because is so similar to Java, PHP and so on. But then problems begin.

Why there is the need of calling `Student.prototype` <s>and `Student.prototype.constructor`</s>?

A clear explanation is needed. Why this code:

```javascript
// define the Student class
function Student() {
  // Call the parent constructor
  Person.call(this);
}

var student1 = new Student();
```

is not enough for inheritance to work?

**EDIT**: regarding the constructor thing, it has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor)

Comment: "Object-Oriented JavaScript" doesn't exists, Javascript is Prototype Oriented and you must adapt your Object-Oriented approaches to Prototypes.

Comment: @Chiguireitor i didn't write the documentation title, you know...

Comment: @pimvdb you're partially right. My question overlaps that posted by you for the constructor thing. But it's not exactly the same: i'd like to know why the second statement is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
function Student() {
  Person.call(this);
}

var student1 = new Student();
```

because `Person`'s prototype properties are not available on `Student` instances. `Person.call(this)` merely calls `Person` with a specific `this` value (namely the `Student` instance). But the `Person` function is completely empty - so here it doesn't do anything. There is no relation between `Student` and `Person` other than the useless `Person` call.

To get `Person`'s functions the `.prototype` assignment is necessary.

Before:

```
<a Student instance>
  its prototype: Student.prototype, with all student functions
    its prototype: Object.prototype
```

After:

```
<a Student instance>
  its prototype: <a Person instance>, with all student functions if you add them
    its prototype: Person.prototype, with all person functions
      its prototype: Object.prototype
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Node.js, I would suggest looking into ECMAScript 5 methods for object creation. [MDN has a page here which might be a good guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited). See also [John Resig's overview](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/) of the new method. Prototypal inheritance is hard to get your head around when coming from a classical OO language like Java. Good luck!