# is setting the 'constructor' property necessary for proper JS inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor)

I'm struggling to understand the necessity of setting the 'constructor' property of a javascript object to the subclass when building a hierarchy. I find that the code below does what is expected without changing the constructor property, but in almost all references I find about the subject the constructor is set explicitly. Am I missing something ? (I don't find any explicit use of it in the ECMAScript specs either).

```
A = function() {
    this.value = "a";

    this.A = function() {
        window.alert( this.value + " instanceof A : " + ( this instanceof A ) );
    }
}


B = function() {
    this.value = "b";

    this.B = function() {
        window.alert( this.value + " instanceof B : " + ( this instanceof B ) );
    }
}

B.prototype = new A();

test = function() {
    var b = new B();
    b.A();
    b.B();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, proper JS inheritance means putting methods in the prototype:

```
var A = function() {
    this.value = "a";
};

A.prototype.A  = function() {
        window.alert( this.value + " instanceof A : " + ( this instanceof A ) );
};

var B = function() {
    this.value = "b";
};
```

Secondly, don't run the constructor when establishing a prototype chain:

```
B.prototype = Object.create( A.prototype );
```

Whenever you reassign the entire `.prototype`, you are completely overwriting the object. So the constructor
property needs (If it's going to be used) to be reassigned:

```
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.B = function() {
    window.alert( this.value + " instanceof B : " + ( this instanceof B ) );
};
```

`Object.create` is not supported in older browsers but you can do something like:

```
Object.create = Object.create || function( proto ) {
     if( proto == null ) {
         return {};
     }
     function f(){}
     f.prototype = proto;
     return new f();
};
```

Comment: It's only necessary to set the `constructor` property if your code has some expectation of using it. Personally I find it entirely useless.

Comment: @TimDown not necessarily your code, iirc, the es5-shim requires constructor property to be set for `getPrototypeOf`

Comment: That's not a proper shim then.

Comment: @TimDown yeah I tried to find the code and it has now been moved to es5-sham.js :P Anyways I have edited in that it's only needed if constructor is going to be used.

Comment: @Timdown, Thanks ! that's what I figured as well, but wasnt sure.

Comment: @Esailija Thanks a lot for your answer, I understand now that because I create a new object for the prototype that the constructor is overwritten. shouldve seen that myself. I'm new to JS from C++ and am a bit baffled by the amount of different ways that ppl approach this. your insights helped a lot.

Comment: @Esailija, by the way, why is it that "proper JS inheritance means putting methods in the prototype", but the approach I used for the example code works fine, what is 'improper' about that ?

Comment: @JochemVanDerSpek If you create functions in a constructor, those functions are recreated (Recreation = creating a new function object and referencing environment) every time the constructor is called (so every time you create an instance) whereas with a function in prototype, that function is reused. It works fine for now because you are not using any state, if you were to define variables in the constructor and then reference them in methods, all the instances of B would actually share the same inherited state. Also, see http://jsfiddle.net/bUyBa/

Comment: @Esailija Yes, that figures & makes sense ! thanks.