# Understanding Javascript Prototype Chains and Inheritance - Example

Tags: javascript

Could some javascript ninja explain to me why my constructor is botched here? I feel like I'm implementing the prototype chain correctly. I know I could use `Object.create`, but I'm just interested in understanding why this doesn't work.

```
var Vehicle = function() {}
Vehicle.prototype.accelerate = function() { console.log('VRRRROOOOOOOM') }
Vehicle.prototype.brake = function() { console.log('SCREEEEECH') }

var Car = function() {}
Car.prototype = new Vehicle
Car.prototype.openTrunk = function() { console.log('POP') }
Car.prototype.closeTrunk = function() { console.log('CLUNK') }

// Test
var mazda = new Car
console.log(mazda) // prototype chain is right
console.log(mazda.constructor === Car) // should be true
console.log(mazda.constructor === Vehicle) // should be false
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6j43r8qg/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `constructor` property is defined on the prototype.

```
Car.prototype = new Vehicle
```

overrides the prototype and assigns an instance of `Vehicle` to it. All `Vehicle` instances inherit `constructor`, which points to `Vehicle`, from `Vehicle.prototype`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But who's fault is this, mine or javascript's?

Comment: Yes. That's why you typically set `Child.prototype.constructor = Child;` after you overwrote the prototype. See [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8453887/218196)

Comment: @SpencerAvinger: Not sure if one can speak of "fault" here. You overwrote `Child.prototype` which contained the `constructor` property. So I guess its your fault?

Comment: In a perfect world, wouldn't the `prototype.constructor === Vehicle` and `mazda.constructor === Car`? Because Vehicle made Car.prototype, and Car made mazda?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe in a perfectly world `constructor` would not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

Also I think `instanceof` would be the way to check if something is a something

```
console.log(mazda) // prototype chain is right
console.log(mazda instanceof Car) // should be true
console.log(mazda instanceof Vehicle) // should be *true?!*
```