# Prototypical inheritance: constructor of child

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I was playing around with prototypical inheritance, and bumped into something I found a bit remarkable. Here is the case:

```
function Parent(){ 
    this.name = "parent"; 
    this.age = 30; 
}; 

var parent = new Parent();  
console.log(parent.constructor); //Prints function Parent();

function Child(){
    this.name = "child"; 
    this.age = 10; 
}; 

var child = new Child(); 
console.log(child.constructor); //prints function Child() 

Child.prototype = new Parent(); //Set inheritance 
console.log(Child.prototype.constructor); //prints function Parent() as expected 

var child_2 = new Child(); 
console.log(child_2.constructor); //prints function Parent() ?? 

console.log(child_2.name); //Yet prints child, meaning the child's constructor is still function Child()
```

Although I am not surprised that the constructor of `Child` is `function Parent()` after the inheritance is defined, I am a bit surprised that the constructor of `child_2` is `function Parent()`, because the property set in the constructor body of `Child`, ie.

```
this.name = "child"
```

Is still executed.

Is there a practical reason behind this occurrence?

http://jsfiddle.net/7yobzt0u/1/

Comment: Well, `child2` inherits the `.constructor` property from `Child.prototype`, so if you expect the one why don't you expect the other?

Comment: Well, I would expect the constructor property to be `function Child()` because this would be the actual constructor of `child_2`. The inheritance only takes place via the prototype property of `Child`, which is overridden by the constructor Child itself.

Comment: The `.constructor` properties on the prototypes don't care what function was called to construct an instance.

Comment: you can't set constructor read this http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that's what I figured out... I expected it to be always 1-1 correct (construct property / constructor function to construct the instance). It seems this wasn't the case anymore after messing around; made it a bit confusing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) touch on this a little bit, but mostly just reference [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor) for the answer.

As you have seen, `constructor` is a property on a function's `prototype` not the object itself. The only reason `myObj.constructor` returns something is because `myObj`'s *`[[Prototype]]`* points to its constructor function's `prototype` property.

When you said: `child.prototype = new Parent()` you made `Child.prototype` point to an "instance" of the parent "class".

Then, when you said `child_2 = new Child()` that instance is what got copied to `child_2`'s *`[[Prototype]]`*

So when you said `console.log(child_2.constructor)` the lookup chain was as follows:

1. Is `constructor` in `child_2`?  --  NO, follow the *`[[Prototype]]`*
2. We landed in this object, (which is an "instance" of the `Parent` class). Is `constructor` here?  -- No, follow the *`[[Prototype]]`*
3. We are now in the `Parent.prototype` object, is `constructor` here?  --- Yes! return it.

Rather than using `new` I suggest setting child's prototype with [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) but I suppose that's neither here nore there in regards to this question. Regardless, you need to set the `constructor` property manually, as referenced in the docs.

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); 
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. But how then can it be explained that when the prototype property of `Child` is replaced by the one of `Parent` (and thus also the constructor on the prototype), the constructor Child (where the name of the child is set) is still called in the first place?

Comment: `constructor` is specified as: 'Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.' It doesn't have to point to the function that created the instance itself.  Here's the doc's for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor             I highly suggest you read that SO answer i linked to in the question

Comment: My misunderstanding came from the assumption that the construct property was always meant to reflect that function that constructs the object (which for me seemed logical), but apparently it doesn't. Following the logic in your answer, I can see why the construct property returned function Parent.