# How to visualize representation of Function constructor objects?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, function-constructor

For below code,

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}
```

below is my understanding on visualizing the representation of above code,

[image]

For below code,

```
function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

below is my understanding on visualizing the representation of above code,

### [image]

Are the above diagrams an accurate representation of the prototype chain created by this Javascript code?

*Note: Javascript beginner*

Comment: You should come with concrete issues rather than "is my code ok?"...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Please don't recommend sites if you aren't familiar with what's on topic there. This question is clearly not for Code Review, and is probably not good for Programmers either.

Comment: @overexchange - this wouldn't fare well on Programmers.

Comment: @overexchange I believe the actual problem with this question right now is that it's unclear. You initially appear to be asking "Is this flowchart an accurate representation of the prototype chain created by this Javascript code?" but then at the end you ask "What is the purpose of `constructor`?" as if these flowcharts are not your own and you don't understand them yourself.

Comment: @overexchange The other reason its unclear is that the title is misleading, as this has nothing to do with employees and managers. It might help to rewrite the title in terms of what this is actually about, namely prototypes and objects.

Comment: check this out http://www.objectplayground.com/

Comment: @overexchange Seems okay to me now. The only other thing I'd comment on is that __proto__ and .prototype are not completely different things as implied by these charts, but of course that's part of the answer.

Comment: I believe `Employee`'s `__proto__` is not `Function.prototype`. Since you included `name` and other properties of `Employee`, you probably are talking about an *instance* created by the constructor. `new Employee().__proto__` is `Employee.prototype`.

Comment: @Ixrec You're wrong. I know JavaScript and I work with it everyday. I still think it's a code review thing, because OP is asking to review the code and check if OP understood the concepts..........or correct the code / statements if something is wrong

Comment: @Ixrec There's no actual issue on this Q&A. At least, for now.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Code review is for reviewing your code. This question is not about reviewing code, instead it's about reviewing concepts.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Maybe the point is that this Q&A has no place on SE network. It should be rephrased...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I still believe it is attempting to ask "Is this flowchart an accurate representation of the prototype chain created by this Javascript code?" That seems like an answerable "issue" to me. Do you think it is not?

Comment: @Ixrec answering issue? check the answer below, I think we need to think, why Bergi is able to answer?

Comment: @Ixrec Is SO is about UML? Is UML programming...?

Comment: @overexchange The fact that someone added an answer doesn't mean that this Q&A fits here in SO..... BTW I'm not a moderator, so it's just my opinion.

Comment: @overexchange BTW, if you check the close votes, 3 other users have voted that's too broad like me..........

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer If you feel the question is too broad, Bergi's answer will narrow your thoughts on this. It perfectly answered my question.

Comment: @overexchange This does demonstrate nothing, but if you could get what you expected adding this Q&A, there's no discussion here ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is fine on the first look (except maybe for ugly graphics, but that wasn't the question). If you care for UML, you should not put `__proto__`<sup>1</sup> and `prototype` next to each other but rather one above the other.

Also, it's important to notice that the `Employee` constructor function does not have `.name`<sup>2</sup> and `.dept` properties. A `new Employee` *instance* would have these.

In the second there are a couple more mistakes:

- Again, the `Manager` function does not have a `reports` property. A `new Manager` instance would have `name`, `dept` and `reports` properties.
- The right prototype object is `Manager.prototype`, not `Employee.prototype` (of which you have two). That's just a labeling issue of course, but still important for precise referencing the graphics.
- The `Manager.prototype`'s `__proto__` is not `Object.prototype`, but rather `Employee.prototype` - that's what you've used `Object.create` for.
- The `Object.create(…)` should not label the arrow, but rather the object itself (of course that's more a style issue, you don't use a [spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram), do you?)
- The `Manager.prototype` does not have a `constructor` property. It does inherit the one from `Employee.prototype` though. You should consider creating one in your code though, see [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8453887/1048572). It would then point to `Manager`.

<sub>1: Actually, `__proto__` is a getter/setter property on the `Object.prototype` object. The real, internal prototype link (that is only accessible via `Object.set/getPrototypeOf`) is typically designated as *[[prototype]]*.

2: In fact, the `Employee` function does have a [`.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), but not the one you meant.</sub>

Comment: After saying `obj = new Manager()`, [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Javascript_Programming/blob/master/Topic7_WorkingWithObjects/hierarchy.png) is the representation after reading your answer.  Is the representation correct?

Comment: Is this representation correct [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Javascript_Programming/blob/master/Topic7_WorkingWithObjects/hierarchyUsingNew.png), on using `new Employee` instead of `Object.create(Employee.prototype)`?

Comment: No, the *[[prototype]]* (`__proto__`) of a `new Employee` (your `WorkerBee.prototype`) is `Employee.prototype`, not `Employee`. Apart from that, the `WorkerBee.prototype` is correctly pictured having `name` and `dept` properties, which a prototype shouldn't really have with proper inheritance.

Comment: I have one similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521184/how-to-use-prototype-property-amidst-designing-a-function-type-object).