# Role of 'prototype' property amidst design of `function` type object?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

As per the understanding, The main purpose for the existence of `prototype` property in a `function` type object is to allow properties/methods sitting under `prototype` to get inherited by other objects. This enables prototypical inheritance.

Considering `window['Number']` function type object,

In general, Idea is to understand the thought process on what comes under `prototype`. So. I would like to take a specific example i.e., `Number`, with below questions.

From design perspective, how would I understand,

1)

why `parseFloat()`/`parseInt()`/`isFinite()`/`isInteger()`/`isFinite()`/`isNaN()`/`NEGATIVE_INFINITY`/`NaN`

are part of `function` type object `Number`?

2)

why methods `toExponential()`/`toFixed()`/`toPrecision()` are part of `Number.prototype` object?

*Note: Have an idea on class based inheritance using java syntax, where both static/instance members can be inherited.*

Comment: `parseFloat` / `parseInt` became part of `Number` object only since ES6.

Comment: Javascript Advanced: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Answer (score 1):

If you understand classic class based inheritance, then `Number.parseFloat` is a *static class method*, while `Number.prototype.toFixed` is an *instance method*. The "class methods" do not need an instance of `Number` to work, you simply call them directly as `Number.parseFloat(foo)`. Instance methods on the other hand require an instance first:

```
var foo = new Number(bar);
foo.toFixed();
```

Comment: Are you saying that always *instance members* go in `Number.prototype`? But my definition above says, members(properties/methods) that needs to get **inherited** by other objects had to be part of `Number.prototype` **and** this has nothing to do with *static member* or *instance member*, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Members on `prototype` will be available to all instances of the object. Members of simply `Number`, the constructor function, aren't. If you didn't put these members on the prototype, you'd have to put them on each constructed object individually, duplicating them each time. On the `prototype`, the same function can be shared by all instances.

Comment: Yes, this also trickles down to further inheriting classes. But a single instance also "inherits" its members from its constructor's prototype.

Comment: For your point: *you'd have to put them on each constructed object individually*. Can't we say `Employee.call()` in `function Manager()` instead?

Comment: I'm missing some context here, I don't know how those are related. However, I mean this: `function Employee () { this.getName = function () { .. }; }`, vs. `Employee.prototype.getName = function () { .. }`. In the first case, the constructor function is creating an individual `getName` function for each object; that means there's lots of copies of the `getName` function. Using `prototype`, there's only one such function, which all `Employee` objects share. *The instances inherit that function from the prototype.*

Comment: However, I have a feeling that we're not really on the same track here, and little snippets in comments won't bring a lot of clarity to either side. Perhaps a new question with more details about what you do understand and what you don't understand is in order.

Comment: For your point: *Using prototype, there's only one such function, which all Employee objects share.* . Instead of funtion, If I take a property `Employee.prototype.count = 0;` then every object has its own copy of `count`.

Comment: If at some point you do `this.count = 1`, then yes, *you're assigning a new `count` property to the current object*, overriding the prototype. Try this with a *mutable* value instead: `Employee.prototype.foo = []`, `this.foo.push('bar')`.

Answer (score 1):

Properties declared on the prototype object are visible from all instances. Thus:

```
var n1 = new Number(1), n2 = new Number(2);
```

Those are two instances of Number, and via each instance it's possible to call the functions on the Number prototype:

```
alert( n2.toExponential() ); // "2e+0"
```

Because of the way that function invocation works in JavaScript, the `.toExponential()` function in that example will be invoked with `this` referring to the number instance used to make the function call — `n2` in this case.

Now, the `.toExponential()` function *could* have been defined as a property of the Number constructor itself, but then the parameter would have to be passed explicitly (like `Number.toExponential(2)`). That's not how the runtime was designed, however. As with so many "why?" questions about how languages and APIs work, it's ultimately just a design preference on the part of the language designers. It should be clear that something like `.parseFloat()` would really *not* make any sense as a prototype method, because the whole point of `.parseFloat()` is to turn something that's *not* a number into a number. (It could have been added to one or more *other* prototype objects, but again the preference of the language designers was to just make it a callable function on the Number constructor itself; that's a recent ES6 addition to the spec of course.)

Finally note that in the particular case of the Number constructor, it's pretty rare that you'd actually explicitly instantiate a number object. Generally that happens implicitly when a number primitive value is used with the `.` or `[ ]` operators as if it were an object reference. Primitives are *not* objects, but the language automatically wraps a primitive value in a Number object in those cases, so the first example above would work the same if it were written like this:

```
var n2 = 2;
alert(n2.toExponential());
```

The variable `n2` has a plain primitive `2` in it, but that will be wrapped in a Number instance in order to allow the method call.

Comment: So, again the thought process is going around like, whichever method is instantiable, goes under `prototype`. In general, Is that the real thought process one has to take with to design any Function constructor?

Comment: @overexchange the prototype is where you put methods that all instances should be able to use. If the method really has nothing to do with any particular instance, but is still relevant to the functionality of the type of object you're designing, then you can make the function a property of the constructor. It's similar to the sort of decision you make in a language like C++ or Java when deciding if a method is a plain method or a static "class" method.

Comment: Apart from method, Does this point also holds good for properties as well?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you mean a program design perspective or a language (core library) design perspective, so I'll try to answer both.

Before we begin, please forget "class" or "instance" or "static".
JavaScript is not class based.
There only object and inheritance.

Now, let's see the object diagram.

[image]

Note that `new Number` does *not* inherits `Number`.

Neither `prototype` nor `constructor` is an *inheriting* relationship.

This means number instances inherits `toExponential`, `toFixed`, etc. but does not inherits `parseFloat`, `parseInt` etc.
So you call them like `Number.parseFloat()` and `new Number(n).toFixed()`.

This is how JS is designed.  If you don't like it you can design your own Number library.

For example, you may create your own Number that has toFixed methods on the Number object rather than on its prototype object, like this:

```
var SheepyNumber = {
   toFixed: ( n ) => Number.toFixed( n )
}
SheepyNumber.toFixed( 3.14159265358979323846 ) // Evaluates to '3'
```

> Do not add `toFixed` to `Number` object.  It may work for now,
>   But if later specifications introduces this function with *any* different in parameter or logic,
>   then your program may break when you use the standard implementation,
>   or a third party library may break if you keep your own implementation.
>   Either way, you lost.

Which leave us the question, why does JS not put  `toFixed` to `Number`, like we just did, but instead put `toFixed` to `Number.prototype`?

The obvious answer is this is more object-oriented.
Since `new Number` has an internal `value` property, `toFixed` can take that value, instead of taking in an extra argument.

The real answer is no one knows.
JavaScript copied Java for its core API - you can find most of these methods in the Java [Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) class.
Some of these Java methods are [instance methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatValue--) (corresponds to methods on `Number.prorotype`), some are [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY) (corresponds to methods on `Number`), but most are *both* - including [a counterpart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intValue--) of toFixed.

Why JavaScript did not put `isFinite` or `isNaN` to `Number.prototype`?

Why did no browsers implement `toFixed` on `Number` which can co-exists with the one on `Number.prototype`, during the first browser war that shaped the JavaScript as we know now?

Language design is an art.
And you may not always know who is responsible or why, because it has been shaped by many hands.

Comment: So, that means, if there is something like `Number.prototype.count` whose  initial value is 0, then every instance of `Number` will have its own copy of `count`. So, Whichever member is instantiable MUST go under `prototype`, whichever member is not instantiable MUST be part of function constructor. Is this the rule of thumb?

Comment: @overexchange Please stop the class / instance nonsense, because it is not.  When `my_number` inherits Number's `count` property, the count is still *the* `Number.prototype.count`, *not* my_number's count, until you *set* my_number's count which create the count property *on my_number*. This can be done in the constructor but not always. After it is set, if you delete Number.prototype.count, my_number will still retain its own count, as they are now different properties on different objects.  Prototype allows you to *share* properties, so that you don't need to duplicate them in constructor.