# Need to print the shape of an object, using inheritance, instances, and prototypes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to print the shape of the object in the constructor `Shape()`, in which the instances of *'triangle'* and *'square'* inherit `Shape()` constructor. I then call a method inside `Shape()`, called `get_type` to display the shape type.

```js
function Shape() {
  this.type = '';

  this.get_type = function() {
    console.log(this.constructor)
  }
}

function Triangle(s1, s2, s3) {
  this.side1 = s1;
  this.side2 = s2;
  this.side3 = s3;
}

function Square(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
  this.side1 = s1;
  this.side2 = s2;
  this.side3 = s3;
  this.side4 = s4;
}

var triangle = new Triangle(10, 8, 15);

Triangle.prototype = new Shape();
console.log(Triangle.prototype); //Shows the Shape() function on console.
console.log(triangle.side1, triangle.side2, triangle.side3) //Shows the Triangle constructor works.
console.log(triangle.type); //Undefined

triangle.get_type(); // Get a not a function error.
```

Comment: Please see [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/218196) . But since you are using Node.js, you really should be using [`class`es](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). `get_type` will only work if you are fixing the `constructor` property. See [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8453887/218196) for that.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the prototype of the Triangle function after you've already used it to construct your triangle object.  Changing Triangle.prototype to refer to a new object will not change the prototype of triangle.

Move the line `Triangle.prototype = new Shape()` to be above `var triangle = new Triangle(10, 8, 15);` if you want triangle to inherit methods and properties from Shape.

Comment: That alone won't make the `get_type` function work though.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes, without other changes it will return Shape() and not Triangle().  Fixing that would require setting Triangle.prototype.constructor manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have several issues:

1. Your `get_type` function should be added to the prototype so as to avoid creating a new method for every Shape instantiated.
2. `new Triangle` should not be called before `Triangle` is made to inherit from `Shape` (by setting `Triangle.prototype = new Shape`).
3. You have to manually set `Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle`. (For the rationale, see [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor).)

```js
function Shape() {
    this.type = ''
}

Shape.prototype.get_type = function () {
    return this.constructor
}

function Triangle(s1, s2, s3) {
    this.type = 'triangle'
    this.side1 = s1
    this.side2 = s2
    this.side3 = s3
}

Triangle.prototype = new Shape
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle

function Square(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
    this.type = 'square'
    this.side1 = s1;
    this.side2 = s2;
    this.side3 = s3;
    this.side4 = s4;
}

var triangle = new Triangle(10, 8, 15)

console.log(Triangle.prototype) //=> [Shape]
console.log(triangle.side1, triangle.side2, triangle.side3) //=> 10, 8, 15
console.log(triangle.type); //=> 'triangle'
console.log(triangle.get_type()) //=> [Function Triangle]
```

Comment: `triangle.get_type()` returns the `Shape` function, not `Triangle`.

Comment: Just solved that problem. Had to set the `constructor` property of the new prototype manually.

Comment: how come you put the get_type function outside the Shape() constructor? Does it matter? And also, I am not suppose to have the type property.

Comment: I defined `get_type` outside of the constructor because that ensures only a single function is ever created to act as that method. Your code generated a new function *per object* instantiated, which is unnecessary. You can delete the `type` property without changing the other functionality.

Comment: `Triangle.prototype = new Shape()).constructor = Triangle` In this part, are you first inheriting the properties of the Shape function/constructor and then making the Shape() function/constructor inherit the properties of the Triangle function/constructor?

Comment: Yeah, that could be better written as two lines. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Aren't you essentially inheriting the Triangle constructor into the Triangle Constructor? Why would we have to re inherit the Triangle constructor when that what we started off with? Isnt the `Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle` making the Triangle constructor have its properties plus the additonal properties of Shape()?

Comment: I understand your confusion; this is a difficult topic and probably not well-suited for the comments section. There is [an existing answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor) that might shed some light on that technique.

Answer (score 0):

You have the prototype attached after the object has already been initialized. Moving your prototype assignment before you create the triangle object, would give you access to get_type.

However, because the way you are assigning the prototype, you dont get the reference of actual constructor function name.Primary reason for this behaviour is that you are actually creating an instance of Shape object independent of the constructor and referencing that instance as a prototype for Triangle / Square. Shape constructor doesn't get executed when you instantiate Triangle / Square constructors.

To get around this issue, you could use [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object).

You could use the code snippet as reference.

In the snippet, you could see the Shape constructor is being called on each Triangle / Square object instantiations and now, you could see the constructor reference as Triangle / Square as per the instance.

But this approach has its own drawback, as you could see any methods that are defined on the prototype of Shape aren't available on the Traiangle / Square. To make this work, you need to have your methods in Shape constructor and not use prototype, if you are ok with it.

```js
function Shape() {
  this.type = 'emptyString';

  this.get_type = function() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name)
  }
}
Shape.prototype.getSomeValue = function() {
  console.log("1234");
}

function Triangle(s1, s2, s3) {
  Shape.call(this);
  this.side1 = s1;
  this.side2 = s2;
  this.side3 = s3;
}

function Square(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
  Shape.call(this);
  this.side1 = s1;
  this.side2 = s2;
  this.side3 = s3;
  this.side4 = s4;
}

var triangle = new Triangle(10, 8, 15);

console.log(Triangle.prototype); //Shows the Shape() function on console.
console.log(triangle.side1, triangle.side2, triangle.side3) //Shows the Triangle constructor works.
console.log(triangle.type); //Undefined


triangle.get_type();

var square = new Square(2, 2, 2, 2);
console.log(square.side1, square.side2, square.side3, square.side4);
console.log(square.type);
square.get_type();

try {
  triangle.getSomeValue();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
try {
  square.getSomeValue();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

Comment: What did you change and why? Code alone is not that helpful. **Explain** your solution so that others can **learn**.