# Difference in objects created when created using different methods

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

I've created 2 objects (object1 and object2) using different ways. 
I found no difference between them, except for the way how it is displayed in the Chrome Dev Console (see this in the below screenshot)
[image]

```
var F;

function create(parent, properties) {
  F = function(p) {
    for(var i in p){
        this[i] = p[i].value;
    }
  };
  F.prototype = parent;
  return new F(properties);
}

var prop={ p: { value: 42 } };

var masterObject = {a: "masterObject value"}

var object1 = create(masterObject, prop);

var object2 = Object.create(masterObject, prop);
```

Following are my questions:

1. As I'm following different ways to create objects, will there be any difference between the objects - object1 and object2?
2. What is the difference that can be seen in the above screenshot (encircled in red)?

Comment: The *constructor* is different. *F* vs. *Object*

Comment: When I check the constructor for both objects the result is same:  `function Object() { [native code] }`

Comment: wow, looks like your code creates some funny chaos to the prototype.constructor... See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Both Objects have the same properties, and inherit from the same object. However, theres a small difference:

```
new F();
//vs.
Object.create(F.prototype);
```

The *constructor*  (the function called to build the object) *should be* different:

```
object1.constructor!==object2.constructor
```

So these objects *should not be* equal, however it has no real effect as the constructor is rarely used.

*Should* because basically

```
F.prototype=parent;
```

breaks the whole thing, as *F.prototype.constructor* is initialized with *F* , so youre overridding this. More info at
[Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor)

Comment: I think you've missed a point, `object2` is created out of `masterObject` and not `F.prototype`. So, when I do `object1.constructor!==object2.constructor` it returns `false`.

Comment: @TempO'rary no. console.log(F.prototype===masterObj)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a function to a variable, you created a named function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

They are functionally the same.