# should I use the constructor or the instance when referencing an object's property from another constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

While I am writing a constructors' methods like the "runGame" method of the "Game" constructor, if I need to reference a property of the "GameBoard" constructor should I use the name of the constructor, like this:

```
function Game(){
   this.runGame(){
     var someProp = GameBoard.otherProp;
   }
}
```

or do I have to create an instance of the constructor object first and then refer to the instance like this.

```
var newGameBoard = new GameBoard();

function Game(){
   this.runGame(){
     var someProp = newGameBoard.otherProp;
   }
}
```

Comment: We can't answer the question, because your "to" form is invalid, you have a syntax error as of the `{` after `this.runGame()` inside `Game`. It matters, because if we don't know how your objects are *really* organized, we can't tell you how to correctly deal with them.

Comment: There should be *very little* code in the constructors - perhaps, creation/assignment of the relevant objects that are intrinsically available. Most work (including access to other objects, as required) happens in the methods.

Comment: The "to" isn't part of the code. I was trying to show that the code was being converted from one format to another. I probably should have just left that whole first portion out.  I will edit the question.

Comment: @Drazah: The code in the question remains a syntax error. It's great people have tried to help (though I would argue they should have waited until the question was clear), but really, code without syntax errors so we know what you're doing is the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question in the right way, what you need is *composition* and you need to inject associated instances during construction time:

```
function Game(gameBoard) {
   this.gameBoard = gameBoard;
}

Game.prototype = {
    runGame: function() {
        // You access injected GameBoard through the 
        // own Game object's property "this.gameBoard"
        var someProperty = this.gameBoard.someProperty;
    }
};

var gameBoard = new GameBoard();
var game = new Game(gameBoard);
```

Further reading:

- [Dependency injection (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
- [Object composition (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

Comment: If you're going to replace the object referenced by the `prototype` property, be sure to set `constructor` correctly.

Comment: Yes ! Faster, shorter and better than my answer. @T.J.Crowder I didn't understand your comment, do you mean we should define a constructor inside the prototype object ? I never did that, never had any problem but please enlighten me

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand that this is a notice for the OP, isn't it?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Well, not really. If you're going to have an example advocating doing something they're not doing (replacing the `prototype` property), it's important to show doing it correctly.

Comment: @KiJéy: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - Thanks!  I am new to writing object oriented javascript and your example seems like a much better approach then what I was doing. Those Wikipedia links give a great explanation of these techniques. Thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks ! Good to know !

Answer (score 1):

If every Game has a GameBoard, it should be a property:

```
function Game(){
  this.board=new Board();
}

Game.prototype.runGame=function(){//real inheritance
  var someProp = this.board.otherProp;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `GameBoard`(s) belong to the `Game` in your logic, here's how I'd do it

```
var Game = function(params) {
    this.options = params.options; // it could prove useful to instanciate a game using a set of rules
    this.gameBoards = params.gameBoards; // Already instanciated gameBoard(s)
    this.activeGameBoard = null; // if there are many gameboards it might be a good idea to keep track of the one that's currently active
    this.prop = '';
    // ... Initialize all the properties you need for your Game object
}

Game.prototype = {
    runGame: function(gameBoardIndex) {
        this.activeGameBoard = this.gameBoards[index];
        this.someProp = this.activeGameBoard.someProp;
    }
}
```

I know I'm assuming a lot of things but I can't help it, it reminds me the only project I worked on that involved games and gameboards :p

Comment: If you're going to replace the object referenced by the `prototype` property, be sure to set `constructor` correctly.

Comment: @Ki jey - Thanks!