# why override constructor field with inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Why we need set `Child.prototype.constructor` property to `Child` after inheritance. For example

```
function Parent(a){
    this.a = a;
}

function Child(a, b){
    Parent.call(this. a);
    this.b = b;
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child // 1)**
```

As I see the instance of constructor will be the same without `// 1) **` line

Why we need this `// 1) **` line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Because it should not be the same

By the language syntax `Child.prototype.constructor` should be the instance of `Object.create(Parent.prototype).constructor` which is actually `Parent.prototype.constructor`

It then up to implementation or optimization of the engine. But it cannot trusted so that `// 1)` line was to ensure it