# Inheritance, Prototype Function Not Defined

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have two very simple prototypes in Javascript; however, when attempting to ensure one prototype inherits from the other, I am seeing behavior I don't understand. I am following Mozilla Developer Network's [article on inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance):

```
const Model = function (data) {
    this.doSomething(data);
};

Model.prototype.doSomething = function (data) {
    console.log("something");
};

// Second "inheriting" model  
const Word = function (data) {
    Model.call(this, data);
};

// Example use:

let word = new Word({ literal: "duck" });
```

When my code executes the `Model` prototype's constructor, I get an error I do not understand in this context:

> this.doSomething is not a function.

As this is a relatively simple use case of inheritance, it leads me to believe I am missing something, entirely, about the prototype chain.

Is it not possible to call a function defined on an iherited prototype from the inherited prototype's constructor?

Comment: That isn't how inheritance works in JavaScript, there's no inheritance here at all. Word's prototype has nothing to do with Model's, you're simply invoking Model's constructor on an object that has nothing to do with Model.

Comment: @meagar I suspected, as much; however, I've been following MDN's doc.s. I'll post the link.

Comment: You need to keep reading the article, you haven't reached the part that actually involves inheritance, ie "Setting Teacher()'s prototype and constructor reference".

Comment: *face palm* Ugh.

Comment: It's a good question for those of us learning the object model behind JS.  Not sure why you got down voted other then inherit negativity in the coding community.  I learned from your question and the answer below.  A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype) is equivalent to class A: B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just miss the prototype chain

```
Word.prototype = Object.create(Model.prototype);
```

before you call

```
var w = new Word('foo');
```

```js
const Model = function (data) {
    this.doSomething(data);
};

Model.prototype.doSomething = function (data) {
    console.log("something");
};

// Second "inheriting" model  
const Word = function (data) {
    Model.call(this, data);
};

Word.prototype = Object.create(Model.prototype);

var w = new Word('foo');
```

Comment: Is it the case, here, too, that I need to reset the `Word` constructor? i.e. `Word.prototype.constructor = Word`.

Comment: Other questions cover this already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor. In short - you don't always need it.