# javascript inheritance using setPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Examples) we can use `Object.create` to achieve inheritance

Here is an example with a `Rectangle` which inherits from `Shape`

```
function Shape() {}

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this);
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

I am wondering if using `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead of `Object.create` is correct ?

```
function Shape() {}

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this);
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Rectangle.prototype, Shape.prototype);

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

If it's correct, then I am wondering why so many examples show inheritance with `Object.create` because you need to worry about the `constructor` property when using this method.

With `Object.setPrototypeOf` you don't need to redefine the `consctrutor` prop, I find it safer and simpler.

Comment: Setting the `constructor` property is more like a nice-to-have. It is not required.

Comment: it's required if we using in one of our method -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Changing_the_constructor_of_a_function

Comment: That is the nice-to-have I talk about, but if one wanted to, they could keep this information in another way. It is not that JavaScript native methods or operators will break or behave differently if you don't set the `constructor` property. It is only there to facilitate. It is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes your code may rely on the `constructor` property, which allows you to access the constructor without knowing its function name explicitly. But besides that, there is [no real need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8454111/5459839) to set it.

For example, the `instanceof` operator does not depend on it.

If you don't need to bother about it in your own suggested solution, then you also would not need it in the `Object.create` solution.

The reason to prefer the `Object.create` method is that `Object.setPrototypeOf` may impact the efficiency of your code, as is warned about in the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). This does not happen with the `Object.create` method.

Comment: with my solution (using `Object.setPrototypeOf(Rectangle.prototype, Shape.prototype);`) it doesn't reaffect the `Rectangle.prototype` object, so `Cat.prototype.constructor === Cat` returns true (Cat.prototype.constructor is still valid)

Comment: Yes, I see, but still: changing the `prototype` property is a relatively light operation compared to calling `setPrototypeOf`.

Comment: ok so it's preferable to use `Object.create` because of performance

Comment: Yep, it boils down to that.