# How to distinguish HTMLElement from its constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

I'm working on my [LIPS project](https://github.com/jcubic/lips) (Scheme-based Lisp in JavaScript) and I want to add a way to add string representation to any object. The code look like this:

> NOTE: you can ignore scheme code. At the end there is simplified use case, this is only for context and why I need this.

```lisp
(add-repr! HTMLElement (lambda (x) 
                           (let ((tag (--> x.tagName (toLowerCase))))
                             (string-append "<" tag ">" x.innerHTML "</" tag ">"))))
```

it works fine when I evaluate:

```lisp
(document.createElement "span")
;; or
(document.querySelector ".klas")
```

but it have problem while evaluating the code:

```lisp
(let ((div (document.createElement "div")))
  (. div 'constructor 'prototype))
```

and my interpreter thinks that this is instance of HTMLElement, the JavaScript code look like this:

```js
var repr = new Map();
// values in map are lisp lambdas that are JavaScript functions
// keys are constructor functions
...
            var fn;
            if (repr.has(constructor)) {
                fn = repr.get(constructor);
            } else {
                repr.forEach(function(value, key) {
                    if (obj instanceof key) {
                        fn = value;
                    }
                });
            }
            if (fn) {
                if (typeof fn === 'function') {
                    return fn(obj, quote);
                } else {
                    throw new Error('toString: Invalid repr value');
                }
            }
```

I check if obj is instanceof given type (HTMLElement from `add-repr!`) and it return true for prototype.

And throw exception that x.tagName is not defined because it's not instance but prototype.

**To simplify the code** (I've added scheme code for context) this is the code:

```
 document.createElement('div').constructor.prototype instanceof HTMLElement;
```

it return true because prototype was `Object.create(HTMLElement)`. Is there a way to detect if the value is in fact a prototype of any value without have that original value.

```
var x = document.createElement('div').constructor.prototype;
// context is lost I can't access original value
// check if x is instanceof HTMLElement, but also it's constructed value and not prototype of any value.
```

and if you think that you can check if there is constructor value, this circular object:

```
document.createElement('div').constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor
```

to sum this question up I want to detect if value is any of but not both:

```
document.createElement('div')
document.createElement('div').constructor.prototype
```

My idea that just came to my mind while I was writing this was this:

```
var x = document.createElement('div').constructor.prototype;
if (x instanceof HTMLElement && x !== x.constructor.prototype) {
    // real instance
}
```

is this correct approach? I was also looking at `Object.getPrototypeOf` but it just return `HTMLElement` object (the one I'm testing). I need this to work for any nested prototype chain, because it's programming construct and user may use anything.

Comment: What did you try to achieve by accessing `.constructor.prototype` in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi sorry I don't understand, I have a language that can interact with javascript and user may get constructor.prototype in REPL and get not related error, I need to guard my code to not throw not related error when user do that.

Comment: @Bergi in REPL I'm printing representations of the objects, right now I'm printing `#<HTMLElement(div)>"` if it's HTMLelement, I want to give user a way to change it.

Comment: @Bergi also I may put that code in my unit tests I don't want them to fail.

Comment: "*My idea that just came to my mind*" - yes, I'd say that's the correct approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting whether something is a prototype object, irrespective of `HTMLElement`, I would suggest doing

```
hasOwnProperty(x, "constructor") &&
  typeof x.constructor == "function" &&
  x.constructor.prototype == x
```

The context of the expression the user is trying to evaluate doesn't matter, they might as well try printing `(. HTMLElement 'prototype)` directly.

Separately, I would suggest not tying the "representation" function for instances to its constructor through a `Map`. Your `add-repr!` should just create a `.repr()` method on the prototype of the class, using `Symbol("lips-repr()")` as the property key.

Comment: I have another question for something different with Preact `Button.prototype = Object.create(preact.Component)` how to check if Button.prototype is prototype object? Is it possible? I'm trying to figure out why my demo is broken and is_prototype function is one the possible places.

Comment: @jcubic I don't know Preact or its `Button`s, but it's possible they have forgotten [to set the `.constructor` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor) after inheriting from `preact.Component.prototype`.

Comment: Ok, that was my that forget to set constructor. Thanks for the tip.