# Javascript: Why is it Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype) where Foo inherits from Bar

Tags: javascript, prototype

why is it

```
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype)
```

in order to let Foo "inherit" from Bar and not

```
Foo = Object.create(Bar)
```

or at least

```
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar)
```

... because isn't `Bar.prototype` already the "class" which Bar is in turn "inheriting" from ? Speaking of the prototype-chain ([Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor))

But obviously, `Foo.prototype` means some hugely different thing than `Foo.[[Prototype]]`. The first one meaning things that are shared among all the instances of

```
new Foo(args)
```

such as in

```
a = new Foo(args)
b = new Foo(args)
```

Intuitively, `this` and `Foo.prototype` seem more like a distinction for instances between "instance-methods/attributes" on one side and "class-level-methods/attributes" than some kind of inheritance.

Comment: `Bar` is Bar's constructor function. If you want to put Bar's prototype onto your prototype-chain, you'll need `Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype)` accordingly. `Foo = Object.create(Bar)` makes no sense, you'd set `Foo` to an object, which isn't a function, and can't be called, so also not constructed. `Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar)` would let instances-of-Foo's prototype chain have Bar's constructor function in it, and not Bar's prototype, as desired.

Comment: I thought it would be desired to have Bar's constructor function inside Foo.prototype and not again the prototype of Bar. It's hard to wrap my head around this. Because then - and this is just a rhetorical question bc your answer is obviously correct - why even bother having a body to `function Foo();` Whatever, thanks for your answer.

Comment: The constructor function, in the ES6 syntax sugar `class` even called `constructor`, is used to create instances, e.g. `function Foo(x) { this.myInstanceValue = x; }`. Every instance will have its own value for the property `myInstanceValue`. The prototype is one for all, and typically has e.g. functions: `Foo.prototype.printMe = function(){ console.log(this.myInstanceValue); }`. Note that there are many valid reasons to have some functions on instances as well. Now, with `const a = new Foo('hello'), b = new Foo('world');`, `a.printMe === b.printMe`, and try `a.printMe(); b.printMe();`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Foo` and `Bar` are *functions*. That's what constructors must be, in order for them to be called, eg `new Foo()`. So they inherit directly from `Function.prototype`.

Although linked, the constructor functions are *entirely different* from the internal prototype of instances created with them. The `.prototype` property of a constructor accesses the internal prototype of instances. The `.constructor` property of such a prototype accesses the constructor.

These internal prototypes are plain objects, not functions. You wouldn't expect any instance to inherit from `Function.prototype` and be callable.

> But obviously, Foo.prototype means some hugely different thing than Foo.[[Prototype]]

The internal prototype of the Foo constructor is `Function.prototype`.

This is how it looks when properly set up:

```
Object.prototype <- Function.prototype <- Foo
Object.prototype <- Function.prototype <- Bar

Object.prototype <- Bar.prototype <- bar instance
Object.prototype <- Bar.prototype <- Foo.prototype <- foo instance
```

The constructors do not inherit from each other - only the `.prototype`s, the internal prototypes (or `[[Prototype]]`s) of instances inherit from each other, when doing this sort of thing.