# Iterate Constructor Chain Up

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have something like this:

```
function A() {}

function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

function C() {}
C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);

var inst = new C();
```

I can now do inst instanceof C == true, inst instanceof B == true, instanceof C == true.

But how could I "iterate" the constructor functions up starting from the instance of C() so that it'd return function C(), function B(), function A() which I could then use to instantiate another instance.

Comment: what do you mean by iterate functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the prototypes by doing

```
for (var o=inst; o!=null; o=Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
    console.log(o);
// {}
// C.prototype
// B.prototype
// A.prototype
// Object.prototype
```

However, that will only iterate the prototype chain. There is no such thing as a "constructor chain". If you want to access the constructors, you will need to [set the `.constructor` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4944278/1048572) on the prototypes appropriately when inheriting:

```
function A() {}

function B() {}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

function C() {}
C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
C.prototype.constructor = C;

var inst = new C();

for (var c=inst.constructor; c!=null; (c=Object.getPrototypeOf(c.prototype)) && (c=c.constructor))
    console.log(c);
// C
// B
// A
// Object
```

---

> which I could then use to instantiate another instance

You would only need to know of `C` for that, not of the "chain". You may access it via `inst.constructor` if you have set `C.prototype.constructor` correctly.

However, it might be a bad idea to instantiate objects from arbitrary constructors; you don't know the required parameters. I don't know what you [actually want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but your request might hint at a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Go up the chain using the constructor property of the object's prototype.

For example, after your code:

```
 C.prototype.constructor === A
```

is true, as is

```
  inst.constructor.prototype.constructor === A
```

... and so forth.