# The correct way to implement prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

There is already numerous threads about prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, but this is not a copy due to laziness. I have literally read them all and have found almost as many different syntactic approaches as I have found answers, so it appears that I am not the only one that is confused on this subject!

Specifics:

My current approach looks like this.

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;

    this.greeting = function() {
        alert("Greetings, I am " + name);
    }

}

var bob = new Person("bob");
bob.greeting();

var Woman = function(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
    this.gender = "female";
}

Woman.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

var brenda = new Woman("brenda");
brenda.greeting();

Person.prototype.eats = true;

alert(brenda.eats);
```

Having tested the code I have found it works perfectly - as far as I can tell - but I have been told that this is not the best approach and that I should define the constructor like this:

```
Woman.prototype.constructor = Woman;
```

And not use the Person.call method in my actual constructor method. Two things, having been told that I can't see an easy way to then pass in the parameters using the 2nd approach, and also, just why? What I'm doing seems to work fine.

Am I missing something?

Is there some cases where what I'm doing will give unpredictable errors?

Can anyone give a definitive 'correct' approach and the reason for it?

Comment: `prototype.call`? Did you mean `Person.call`?

Comment: I think... and I could be wrong here, that the call method belongs to Object.prototype and is inherited . So Person.call is a shorthand for Person.prototype.call() .. so that's what I ment.

Comment: FYI, `Person.call` is not the same as `Person.prototype.call`. `Person.protoype` is not a function, it cannot be called.

Comment: One last note: `greeting` should really be defined as `Person.prototype.greeting`, not inside the constructor. Otherwise you are not taking advantage of prototypes (sharing data amongst instances).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is, I think, considered to be the best approach. The point you raise however is irrelevant:

```
Woman.prototype.constructor = Woman;
```

is not a replacement for `Person.call(...)`. In fact, those two things have nothing in common, they serve different purposes:

- Calling the parent constructor in the child constructor ensures that the child instance is correctly initialized. It's like calling `super()` in ES6 or other languages.
- Assigning to `constructor` simply restores the original value of `Women.prototype.constructor`. If you did not do that, `brenda.constructor` would refer to `Person`. This doesn't have an impact on the internal workings of your inheritance, but other code that consumes your object might rely on `constructor` having the correct value. See also [Advantages of setting the "constructor" Property in the "prototype"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4944278/218196).

So the answer to your question is: you should do both.

Sometimes you see the assignment taking place as part of the `Object.create` call. This is even more accurate, since it recreates the original characteristics of the property (like non-enumerability):

```
Woman.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {
  constructor: {value: Woman, writable: true}
});
```

---

FWIW, I believe one of the reasons of introducing `class` in ES6 was to reduce the confusion around constructor functions and prototypes. That is not to say that you should not know about it, after all, `class` is more or less just syntactic sugar, but it just makes inheritance a bit easier:

```
class Woman extends Person { // almost like Woman.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)
  constructor(name) {
    super(name); // almost like Person.call, but enforced by the interpreter
    this.gender = "female";
  }
}
```

Comment: Felix, I have no doubt you are correct, but for completeness could you explain why I need to explicitly define the constructor please? To me it seems strange, because clearly when I use the new operator as in woman = new Woman() it is saying that Woman is a constructor. Is this then necessary for objects that inherit from the Woman class?

Comment: Thank you Felix. One other question. As per the answer below, many sources suggest that rather than Woman.prototype = Object.create(Person.protype) - which I understand as making a deep copy of the relevant prototype - they say instead I should simply write Woman.prototype = new Person() ... is this effectively the same thing?

Comment: It can be the same thing, but it's conceptually wrong. See my answer here: [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857).

Comment: Also, `Object.create` doesn't deep copy. It creates a new object with a specific object as its prototype. The prototype is not copied however. This is important, because changes you make to the prototype affect the object (like you did above with `eats`). Maybe that's what you meant, I just wanted to clarify it :)

Comment: `writable: false` maybe? Why would we want others to change it? ;-)

Comment: @thefourtheye: Yeah, that would probably be useful. I'm just setting it to the default values :)

Answer (score 0):

this is OOP approach in JS

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function(){ 
    var newPerson = new Person(this.name);
    alert("Greetings, I am " + name);
    return newPerson;
} 

Person.prototype.toString=function(){ 
    return '[Person "'+this.name+'"]';
} 

Woman.prototype = new Person();

Woman.prototype.constructor=Woman;      

function Woman(name){ 
    this.name=name;
} 

Woman.prototype.toString=function(){ 
    return '[Woman "'+this.name+'"]';
} 

var somePerson = new Person('Mr.');
var myPerson = new Woman('She');
alert('somePerson is '+somePerson);   // results in 'somePerson is [Person "Mr."]' 
alert('myPerson is '+myPerson);             // results in 'myPerson is [Woman "She"]' 

myPerson.greeting();                    // calls a method inherited from Person
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. It has quite a few disadvantages compared to `Object.create`.